# how to input a client order with many itens in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a restaurant pizzeria and I want to input in my mysql database the order of my clients, but I am having a problem how to input more than a type of pizza.

I am using a checkbox to select the items then go to this code:

```
<form id="detalhesdopedido" action="formadepagamento.php" method="post">
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     echo"<table id='t02'>
    <tr>
     <th width='15%'>Quant</th><th width='40%'>Produtos </th><th width='15%'>Total</th>
     </tr>";
     $total = 0;

     if (isset($_POST['ch1'])) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt1'] ;
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td> Produto 1 </td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt1'] * 10  ;
        echo"</td></tr>";
        $total += $_POST['qt1'] * 10;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['ch2'])) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt2'] ;
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td> Produto 2 </td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt2'] * 20.30  ;
        echo"</td></tr>";
        $total += $_POST['qt2'] * 20.30;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['ch3'])) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt3'] ;
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td> Produto 3 </td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt3'] * 30  ;
        echo"</td></tr>";
        $total += $_POST['qt3'] * 30;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['ch4'])) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt4'] ;
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td> Produto 4 </td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt4'] * 40.50  ;
        echo"</td></tr>";
        $total += $_POST['qt4'] * 40.50;
    }

     if (isset($_POST['ch5'])) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt5'] ;
        echo"</td>";
        echo "<td> Produto 5 </td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo  $_POST['qt5'] * 50.45  ;
        echo"</td></tr>";
        $total += $_POST['qt5'] * 50.45;
       }
        echo "</table>";
        echo  "<div id='total'>Valor Total: " .$total. "</div>";
    }
 ?>
<button id="finalizar" type="submit">Finalizar Pedido</button>
                </form>
```

How do I insert this into the mysql database?

I want it to appear like this on the database:

cliente /order/quantity/total price

```
alex/ produto 1 , produto 2/ 2 , 3/ 34.50
```

or does someone know a better way to show me?

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about the structure of your database.

What you can do is to have a few tables like this -

```
Product(_id, productName, price);
Order(_id, clientName, productIds, qtys, total);
```

For the Order table, productIds will be a foreign key to Product(_id) and under it, you can store the productIds for all the ordered products separated by a comma. Same for qtys.

Another approach can be

```
    Order(_id, clientName, productId, qty, total, timestamp);
```

where you can retrieve the records using the **where and order by** clauses

Comment: the structure i want is a table order(ID, Clientname, Product, qty, price, total price), my problem is on how to add more then a product in the same id order also  the price of each product mutilpe of qty(will be price) and then sum of prices( will be total price) everthing in the same order id, sorry about my english